# Typescript: use logger in custom Error class

Tags: typescript, logging, error-handling

I´m trying to create a custon Error Class and within the constructor of that class I want to get my global logger-object (singleton) to log that error to file:

```
export class SystemError extends Error{
    
    private logger:Logger

    constructor(message:string){
        super(message)


        this.logger = Logger.getInstance()
        this.logger.logError(this.message)
    }
}
```

When I execute this (and just this as single line in my test)

```
throw new SystemError("test")
```

I get this in the console

```
SystemError: test
    at start (/home/xxx/projects/xxx/build/src/index.js:11:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xxx/projects/xxx/build/src/index.js:14:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  logger: Logger {
    logfile_timestamp_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD_HHmmss',
    logentry_timestamp_format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
```

The last two lines are just a dump of the instanciated logger object (shortened), but it doesn´t execute the actual logging. I´m getting just the dump and that´s it :-(

Anyone has a tipp for me ?

Thanks guys and Greetings,

JP

Comment: It should be logging but you might be missing the output. And a tip for the logger using `#logger` instead of `private logger` might be better it would prevent your logger's internal structure from being logged when a `SystemError` is thrown.

Comment: Thanks for answer, much appreciated :-) ....  what do you mean by "using #Logger" .... I don´t know this syntax ....and for the "missing output" ... I searched again, but no, there isn´t one :-( ... it´s working sandbox, though :-( ... could it be some tsconfig issue (I´m using the google typescript style (gts) ...... I´m new to typescript so excuse my silly questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found it ..... very strange ..... it really have to do with the private logger at class level. I declared and instantiated the logger locally in constructor now, and now it works :-) ..... Thanks @Eldar for the hint!